# Debian 11: boot keeps halting at or a few lines after "Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen"

Tags: debian

Trying to boot my Debian machine, it keeps getting stuck at the image. Sometimes a line or two after "Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen".

[image]

I can switch to tty2-6 once the screen in the image is reached, but I dont seem to have a network connection despite being on ethernet.
How can I fix this? I've never had this problem before, don't think I've done any installation breaking tinkering since the last time it was bootable (yesterday) either. The only two things I recall doing are:

- Command line equivalent of this line from [here](https://github.com/geeks-r-us/anbox-playstore-installer/blob/master/install-playstore.sh) (I quickly undid it right after):

```bash
        $SUDO cat >/etc/systemd/system/anbox-container-manager.service.d/override.conf<<EOF
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/anbox container-manager --daemon --privileged --data-path=/var/lib/anbox --use-rootfs-overlay
EOF
        $SUDO systemctl daemon-reload
        $SUDO systemctl restart anbox-container-manager.service
```

- and removed reserve space from my two ~2TB HDD partitions for personal files (I have ~300 GB free on the HDD in total, with ~150 GB on both partitions) and my `/home` SSD.

If all fails, can I safely re-install Debian Bullseye without losing all my personal data, installations, and configurations (browser history/configurations, XFCE configurations, etc)? How?